# Generating and verifying password hashes with flask-bcrypt

Tags: python, hash, flask, bcrypt

So I've recently learned how to store passwords in a DB, that is by adding a salt to the plaintext password, hashing it, and then storing the hash.

I'm working on a really small Flask app to try all this out, but I'm having a problem with the password hashing and checking parts of the process. It seems that I"m ending up with two different hashes for the same input and I can't seem to figure out why.

I ran a little experiment in the interpreter to test things out.

```
>>> from os import urandom
>>> salt = urandom(32).encode('base-64')
>>> salt
'+3DejJpQZO9d8campsxOB6fam6lBE0mJ/+UvFf3oG8c=\n'
>>> plaintext_pw = 'archer'
>>> plaintext_pw
'archer'
>>> salted_pw = plaintext_pw + salt
>>> salted_pw
'archer+3DejJpQZO9d8campsxOB6fam6lBE0mJ/+UvFf3oG8c=\n'
>>> from flaskext.bcrypt import Bcrypt
>>> bc = Bcrypt(None)
>>> hashed_pw = bc.generate_password_hash(salted_pw)
>>> hashed_pw
'$2a$12$znMwqAw.GliVE8XFgMIiA.aEGU9iEZzZZWfxej5wSUFP0huyzdUfe'
```

All is working well at this point, but when I turn around and do this:

```
>>> bc.generate_password_hash(plaintext_pw + salt)
'$2a$12$qbywkEjuJgmBvXW6peHzAe.rWjoc.ybFKRNzuZhom2yJSXaMRcVTq'
```

I get a completely different hash, even though I started with the same plaintext_pw and salt. I thought that wasn't supposed to happen? Furthermore each subsequent call to bc.generate_password_hash() gives me different results each time:

```
>>> bc.generate_password_hash(plaintext_pw + salt)
'$2a$12$FAh9r4oaD40mWPtkClAnIOisP37eAT5m.i.EGV1zRAsPNbxg3BlX2'
>>> bc.generate_password_hash(plaintext_pw + salt)
'$2a$12$gluk9RUiR6D0e2p1J.hNgeE3iTFxDUlCNvFJOsCZZk89ngO.Z6/B6'
```

As far as I can tell plaintext_pw and salt aren't changing between calls. I can't seem to spot the error here, could someone explain to me exactly what's happening here, and what it is I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

Ok so it looks like I've solved my problem. Turns out I wasn't using bcrypt properly. Here's what I learned:

The hashes were different each time I called generate_password_hash because bcrypt automatically generates a salt for you and appends it to the hashed password, so no need to generate it with urandom or store it separately.

I didn't talk about this in my post, but its worth noting here anyway -  I assumed that on login you would need to call generate_password_hash() and provide the password from the login form to create a second hash for check_password_hash() to compare against, but that isn't necessary. check_password_hash() can be called with the stored hash and the form password (respectively) and it will automatically take care of salting and hashing the form password, and comparing it to the stored hash.

And with that everything is working fine now. Hope this helps someone else!