# Sending user credentials via angular $http to Flask backend

Tags: python, angularjs, http, post

I am strugling with little problem. I'am creating little project with user authentication. This is my flask code for LOGIN:

```
@app.route('/api/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    json_data = request.json
    user = User.query.filter_by(login=json_data['login']).first()
    print(request)
    print(user.password)
    if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, json_data['password']):
        user.authenticated = True
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        login_user(user, remember=True)
        status = True
        session['logged_in'] = True
    else:
        status = False

return jsonify({'result': status})
```

On the front side (angularJS 1.5) I've created simple form int html, controller, and serivce for handling user login. 
The problem is that when I send my user data the server is returning the 'false' response even when the login and password are proper.

This is my service:

```
attemptAuth(login, password) {
       console.log(login, password);
        return this._$http({
            url: `${this._AppConstants.api}/login`,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
            data: {login: login, password: password}


           }).then(
                // On success...
                      (res) => {
                       console.log(res);
                       return res;

                }
          );
    }
```

This is my controller:

```
 submitForm () {
            console.log(this.formData);

           this._User.attemptAuth(this.formData.login, this.formData.password).then(
                (res) => {
                    this.isSubmitting = false;
                    console.log(res);
                },
                (err) => {
                    this.isSubmitting = false;
                    console.log(err.data.errors);
                }
            )

         }
```

When I am trying to send the data. The backend returns **"POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 200**  Send request is good. But why my credentials from front-end not working with backend ? 
The strange thing is that if i try to send request via python Console using the same credentials
`import requests
import json
d = {'login': 'user123', 'password': 'user321'}
res = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login', data=json.dumps(d), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})`

I get status 200 and return from server **true**
Do I need to use some parameters in my $http method in service ?

cheers

Comment: if the server return false , that mean you send wrong data (not proper or empty ) so try to return the login and password on the server side to see if they reach the server or not

Comment: that's why I've used those "print" methods to see what is happening with my data. And my data is as is should be let's say that I've added a user to the database - login: user123, password: user321 (password is crypted using bcrypt) And when I try to send my data the mentioned print methods are returning data from my front end:  login: user123, password: user321 but it's returning false

Comment: what is `json_data` at server?Is it printing amythinng?

Comment: If i try to send 'login:user123, password: user321' the json_data will be  'login:user123, password: user321' .

Comment: is it possible that the problem is within the hashing function `bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, json_data['password']):`

[check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026004/generating-and-verifying-password-hashes-with-flask-bcrypt)