# How to secure password in a flasks server application?

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple flask server, that catches json webhooks then logins and posts them in an internal application. The problem is I need to have the server online and exposed. The internal application requires a login and exposed the login information. I am trying to find the best way to hide or secure this information.

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
import xmlrpc.client


app = Flask(__name__)


# Tells the server what route and method to use
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':



# Logs in to  server
        url = ""
        db = " "
        username = "  "
        password = " "
```

Comment: You can try using bcrypt to encrypt the passwords with auto generated salts and then probably store that encrypted password in the db

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating and verifying password hashes with flask-bcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026004/generating-and-verifying-password-hashes-with-flask-bcrypt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the [bcrypt](https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/) package? You can use it to hash and verify passwords

Here's an example from their doc:

```py
>>> import bcrypt
>>> password = b"super secret password"
>>> # Hash a password for the first time, with a randomly-generated salt
>>> hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())
>>> # Check that an unhashed password matches one that has previously been
>>> # hashed
>>> if bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed):
...     print("It Matches!")
... else:
...     print("It Does not Match :(")
```